# How to calculate expected value if the probability will be random variable uniformly distributed over a range

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say we are given an event that has fixed value $v$, how can we find its expected value if the probability of the event happening is uniformly distributed random variable in a range $[a, 1], a < 1$.

I tried calculating different integrals, however none of these seemed to make sense.

Comment: It's not so clear what you mean by this.  My interpretation would be: first, pick a number p uniformly from the range [a,1].  Then, sample a random variable that takes the value v with probability p and 0 with probability 1-p.  Then calculate the total expected value.  Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Yeah, I meant this

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of the event happening is $p$, then the expected value is just $pv$.  Since $p$ was drawn uniformly from $[a,1]$, the total expected value should be given by
$$
\int_a^1 pv \cdot \frac{dp}{1-a} = \frac{v}{1-a} \cdot \frac12 (1-a^2)
$$

Comment: That's precisely the expected value of the uniform distribution multiplied by $v$: $\dfrac{v}{1-a}·\dfrac{1}{2}(1-a^2)=v\dfrac{a+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E(V)=E[E(V|X)]=E(vx)=vE(X)=v\frac{a+1}{2}$$